# What is the difference between different display standards?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

I'm looking at my shiny new PC's GPU and Motherboard, and I can see in the motherboard 2 display adapters (DVI-D and VGA) whilst on the GPU I can see 5 (4 HDMI and 1 DVI-D). What is the difference between the 3 standards, VGA, DVI-D and HDMI (aside from the cable)?

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: @Ramhound I know that DVI and HDMI are digital, whilst VGA is analog. I think what I really want to know is _what_ makes them so different (because DVI and HDMI are analog)

Comment: DVI can be both analog and digital and HDMI is digital only.  Have you researched the basics on each type of connection.  You indicating HDMI is an analog connection indicates you might be more confused then you think

Comment: @Ramhound whoops I meant digital...

Comment: So my question remains.  What has your research shown?

Comment: @Ramhound Nothing of value to me. All I can grasp is that DVI and HDMI are digital and VGA is analog. That however doesn't explain it enough to me...

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an analog and a digital signal when it comes to video?

Comment: @Ramhound I can't say I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array)**: is purely analog: <s>low resolution</s>, low quality

**[DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface)**: is the first digital standard, the digital value in the graphics card is passed to the display, which takes care of displaying it. DVI-D is transports only digital data. DVI-A only analog data (useless), DVI-I both.

**[HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI)**: this is the digital standard for home entertainment industry devices, blue-ray players, tv's and so on. Graphics cards have learned to use this after having used DVI for some time. It's a better format than  DVI, as it can include sound and networking data

**[Display Port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)**: Comes after HDMI, at least for PC's as it has a higher bandwidth for more monitors (daisy chaining them), which isn't really a requirement for home entertainment equipment.

Comment: You may want to add the most important technical data to your answer. Only HDMI **2.0** is capable of 4K@60Hz, while DisplayPort 1.3 has no problem of supplying one screen with 4K@120Hz or 2 screens with 4K@60Hz (even going as far as offering 8K@30Hz). This information may be important to someone who really wants to get everything out of their system.

Comment: Your condescension of VGA and analog borders on ignorance.  VGA CRT monitors and projectors were capable of HD resolutions (i.e. in early 1990s)  long before consumers were able to buy any ATSC HD televisions.

Comment: @sawdust adding to this the fact that I studied Media Technology wants me to perform hara-kiri. I should have taken more care.